# PostgreSQL+PHP: "select * from tab where col in ( ? )"

Tags: php, postgresql, binding

the following short test script

```
<?php

define('DBHOST', '/tmp');
define('DBNAME', 'XXX');
define('DBUSER', 'XXX');
define('DBPASS', 'XXX');

$ids = array('OK251562715876', 'OK178469380239');

try {
        $db = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . DBHOST . '; dbname=' . DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS, $options);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sth = $db->prepare('select * from pref_money where id in ( ? )');
        $sth->execute($ids);
        while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                print_r($row);

} catch (Exception $e) {
        exit('Database problem: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

fails with the error:

```
Database problem: SQLSTATE[42P18]: 
Indeterminate datatype: 7 
ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $2
```

If I remove the 2nd element of the array, then it works ok.

Is there maybe a way to make the binding work for array with several elements?

I know that I can prepare a complete SQL statement string by using join() etc. and omiting the question mark, but then I need extra effort to prevent SQL injection in my web script...

Using PostgreSQL 8.4.6 with PHP 5.1.6 under CentOS 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the query with the right number of question marks- to match the length of the array- then pass the contents of the array as the values to `execute`.

Comment: Haven't thought about it, thanks - still better than constructing an SQL query without ? marks

Answer (score 2):

[`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) expects a single argument that is an array of parameters. Each element of that array is treated as a query parameter. So right now PDO "thinks" that you pass two parameters while your query contains only one.

Solution: pass an array with only **one** element (parameter), which is an array: `...->execute(array($ids));`

Answer (score 1):

It would be convenient if bound parameters worked this way, but alas, they do not.  You'd have to do something like:

```
$sth = $db->prepare('select * from pref_money where id in (?, ?)');
$sth->execute($ids[0], $ids[1]);
```

Ugly, and probably not what you want, but you can write some code to make it slightly friendlier (automatically put in the right number of question marks, for example).